# Django fetch firebase User UID

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I'm using [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) to fetch data from firebase in Django and so far it seems to be able to do everything but for some reason, I can't fetch the User UID from the authentication page in firebase. [image] This is necessary for me to be able to do as all my user database nodes are save under the User UID from here. Here is my current attempt but the idToken doesn't return the User UID

```
  token = user['idToken']

  print(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Once authenticated you can call `localId` which will fetch the user UID.

```
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

session_id = user['idToken'
request.session['uid'] = str(session_id)

print(user["localId"])
```